# Why is the treasury yield on Yahoo finance different from that on U.S. Department of Treasury?

Tags: market-data, bond-yields

The 13 Week Treasury Yield on [Yahoo Finance](https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EIRX/history?p=%5EIRX) is

```
Date         Open    High    Low     Close*  Adj. close**   
31 Mar 2020  0.0700  0.0700  0.0280  0.0300  0.0300 
30 Mar 2020 -0.0430  0.0200 -0.0530  0.0130  0.0130 
27 Mar 2020 -0.1080 -0.0580 -0.1080 -0.0580 -0.0580
```

The 3 month Treasury Yield on [U.S. Department of Treasury website](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldYear&year=2020) is

```
03/27/20        0.03    
03/30/20        0.12    
03/31/20        0.11
```

Why are they so different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually written on the treasury page

> Negative Yields and Nominal Constant Maturity Treasury Series Rates
>   (CMTs): At times, financial market conditions, in conjunction with
>   extraordinary low levels of interest rates, may result in negative
>   yields for some Treasury securities trading in the secondary market.
>   Negative yields for Treasury securities most often reflect highly
>   technical factors in Treasury markets related to the cash and
>   repurchase agreement markets, and are at times unrelated to the time
>   value of money.
>
> At such times, Treasury will restrict the use of negative input yields
>   for securities used in deriving interest rates for the Treasury
>   nominal Constant Maturity Treasury series (CMTs). Any CMT input points
>   with negative yields will be reset to zero percent prior to use as
>   inputs in the CMT derivation. This decision is consistent with
>   Treasury not accepting negative yields in Treasury nominal security
>   auctions.

Comment: In other words the yield on the USTR web site is a computed number, not the yield on a specific security.  "The Treasury yield curve is estimated daily using a cubic spline model. Inputs to the model are primarily indicative bid-side yields for on-the-run Treasury securities.", with the additional proviso about negative yields mentioned above. They are points on a mathematical curve obtained through an algorithm, not market quotations.

Comment: Is Yahoo Finance data the actual trade data?

Comment: Probably. It is not clear to me where Yahoo gets ^IRX from. I have more trust in the figure for "Treasury bills (secondary market) 3 months" in the Fed H.15 release, it shows slightly different numbers. But clearly on some days the yield has been negative. https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h15/